# OS taking longer boot time, held for a longer duration at the splash screen

Tags: boot, 16.04, plymouth

OS taking longer boot time, held for a longer duration at the splash screen. I'm unable to understand why is it happening any help would be really helpful to me.  I've attached the process also in the picture which is delaying the entire booting process

[image]

Comment: Run `sudo journalctl -b` to display the log og the last boot and browse it to see where stalls and errors happen. Or put the whole log on pastebin and let us see.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your network drivers.

I believe r8169 is a Realtek network driver. A quick search of `r8169 driver rtl_counters_cond` led me to [this](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/commit/f09cf4b7832d029fb22d8f476eac12fc27dde61f) GitHub commit which contains a fix for the issue (the fix is for Raspberry Pi. I mentioned it for reference purposes only).

The most likely cause is outdated drivers. Assuming you have `sudo` privileges, a simple `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` should suffice. Depending on what version of Ubuntu you have, you may be required to either use the backports repo or upgrade to yakkety.